# How can I retrieve the column names of a table in Apache Derby, via an SQL query?

Tags: derby

I want to retrieve the column names of a table (e.g., `MAIN_ENGINE_DATA`), under a specific schema (e.g., APP) using an **SQL** query.

How can I achieve this in **Apache Derby**?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found the solution. The SQL query would be like:

```
SELECT COLUMNNAME FROM SYS.SYSCOLUMNS INNER JOIN SYS.SYSTABLES ON SYS.SYSCOLUMNS.REFERENCEID = SYS.SYSTABLES.TABLEID WHERE TABLENAME = 'MAIN_ENGINE_DATA'
```

Comment: Also consider using the JDBC DatabaseMetaData class for retrieving schema information from a program; it can be a much easier API to use, sometimes.